# PHP listener script that can read incoming $_REQUEST or $_POST variables

Tags: php, scripting, http-post

I am trying to write a PHP script that listens for incoming $_REQUEST or $_POST variables that are sent by a web application as part of a 2-way communication.

HTTP GET calls will be made to the web app in format similar to [this](https://WEBAPPNAME.com/sendmsg?text=BLAH&replyTo=http://TRAVISNG.com/listener.php).

The WEBAPP will then send a POST response to my listener script (http://TRAVISNG.com/listener.php) and so I was wondering if my php script could parse it without me executing the php script manually?

**Note that I am not referring to writing a script that listens for network requests on a socket.**

Basically, I want to parse the POST data sent by the web app and write it out to a log file. Therefore, every time I run my listener script it will read the log file and print out all the POST responses sent to my listener script.

Here's some of the code that I've written:

```
<?php

    // Read incoming POST request
    if (!empty($_POST)){
        $params = join(" ", $_POST);
        //print_r($params);
        echo "|$params|";
    }

    // Print params & timestamp to file called listenerLog.txt
    $logFile = "http://travisng.com/listenerLog.txt";

    $fileHandle = fopen($logFile, 'a') or die("Unable to open the listenerLog.txt.");
    fwrite($fileHandle, $params);
    fclose($fileHandle);

    $output = file_get_contents($logFile);

    // Print listenerLog.txt
    //echo $output;

?>
```

Cheers,

Travis

Comment: It's not entirely clear how the requests occur, or why this approach is necessary. Maybe you can reexplain what's happening. - As for the "logging" you probably want to store a `serialize`d array, either in a binary file, or for simplicity in the database.

Comment: The structure is like this: User invokes web app through HTTP call -> Web app sends a HTTP POST to the listener.php script as specified in the call -> listener.php reads the HTTP POST and prints it to a log file. This approach is to determine if the web app has been invoked properly and if it does, a valid POST response will be sent to the listener.php script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome this issue, I decided to create a CGI listener script and process REQUEST parameters from there. The CGI script was invoked whenever a GET/POST request came through and the requests were written out to a log file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example call/url they will be in the $_GET global.

So try:

```
// Read incoming POST request
if (!empty($_GET)){
    $params = join(" ", $_GET);
    //print_r($params);
    echo "|$params|";
}
```

You could use `$_REQUEST` - this will contain items `$_GET` and `$_POST` and (depending on version or php.ini config `$_COOKIE` too).

Comment: I've tried using $_GET and $_REQUEST but to of no avail. Hmmm.